# Getting 0 as Http Response Code in ajax request on closed python server

Tags: javascript, python, http, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I am polling my python server by ajax request. When server is on I am getting status code proper as 200, but when I close the server using CTRL+C, i notice that my polling continues. When I printed status code in console got it 0 when server is closed.

When i hit that ajax url on browser with closed server i get temporarily unavailable.

I can't understand why I am getting status code 0? It should be either 404(Not found) or 503(Temporarily not available).

Thanks

Comment: Those values are what the server gives to a response. If you don't have a server, you don't get a response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The server didn't send a response, so there can't be an HTTP status code. See [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-status-attribute):

> The status attribute must return the result of running these steps:
>
> 1. If the state is UNSENT or OPENED, return 0 and terminate these steps.
> 2. If the error flag is set, return 0 and terminate these steps.
> 3. Return the HTTP status code.